# Different results for same principal argument?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading about extraction of roots from complex numbers and here the example that I am having difficulties with:

[image]
(the text within the box)

I get that $1-i = \sqrt{2}cis(-\pi/4)$ and thus that the principal argument is $\pi/4$. I also get how the expressions for $z_k$ are derived - using the fact that $z_k = r_0^{1/n}(cis(\frac{\sigma + 2k\pi}{n}))$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1$.

But if the principal argument of $(1-i)$ is $-\pi/4$ - and we use that to derived the expressions after "We therefore have five values:", how does the author end up with the two expressions after "Writing $z_3$ and $z_4$ with principal arguments, we get"? I mean we already used the principal arguments so what is different this time?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $1-i=\sqrt{2}\left(\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right) + i\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)$ is written with a principal argument but the roots $z_{3}$ and $z_{4}$ are not (their angles $\frac{23\pi}{20}$ and $\frac{31\pi}{20}$ do not lie between $-\pi$ and $\pi$).

So, on the next line, he simply rewrites them with the principal argument

Comment: THANK YOU! I guess everything seems obvious when you have the answer - but... this makes so much sense. Spend hours trying to figure this out - appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

How do you know all the values are distinct unless you make sure their principal arguments are distinct?

In principle , $z_4$ could have been $\frac{39}{40}\pi$, and that would have been identical with the $z_0$ after conversion to principal arguments.  This was not the case, of course, but I mean that is why you’d compare complex numbers this way.